# Javascript - Create objects to push in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, chart.js

I've got two arrays where:

```
var arrayX = ["02/01/2014", "14/10/2014", "03/05/2014"];

var arrayY = [2, 10, 8];
```

I want to create 3 different objects, each one being:

```
 {x: "02/01/2014", y: 2} 
 {x: "14/10/2014", y: 10}
 {x: "03/05/2017", y: 8}
```

and create an array containing all the 3 objects.

So my code is:

```
  var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayX.length; i++){
    
      var object = {x: arrayX[i], y: arrayY[i]};    
      data.push(object);
    
    }
```

But the result that I get is an array with just an object containing three X and three Y:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly7LT.png)

```
var result = [{x:["02/01/2014","14/10/2014","03/05/2017"], y:[2,10,8]}];
```

What can I do?

Comment: *"But the result that I get is an array with just an object containing three X and three Y"* No, it produces an array with three objects, as you've said you want: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/6vbfm07a/ The code is just fine (other than using `var`  ;-) -- in modern JavaScript, don't use `var`, use `let` or `const` ).

Comment: My guess is that your input might be something that you are not expecting. Could you create a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You let me just notice that my 2 arrays (arrayX and array Y) I was receiving were given inside an array each (arrayX = [ ["02/01/2014", "14/10/2014", etc..] ]... Sorry, it was my oversight. (I wasted so much time for nothing)

Comment: Are you logging the wrong object?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that arrayX and arrayY have the same lengths.

```
let arrayX = ["02/01/2014", "14/10/2014", "03/05/2014"];
let arrayY = [2, 10, 8];

let data = [];

for (let i in arrayX) {
    data.push({
        x: arrayX[i],
        y: arrayY[i]
    });
}

console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the OP's code. The only difference is that he uses a temporary variable for the object.

Comment: Did you read the comment where they said that `arrayX` is actually nested a level deep?

Comment: I just read it. apparently his code is working when provided with the expected input. I just assumed it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

One way of merging it would by map over one of the arrays with referring to index in second:

```
const arrayX = ["02/01/2014", "14/10/2014", "03/05/2014"];
const arrayY = [2, 10, 8];

const data = arrayX.map((item, index) => ({
  y: arrayY[index],
  x: item,
}));

console.log(data);
```

it results:

```
[
  { y: 2, x: '02/01/2014' },
  { y: 10, x: '14/10/2014' },
  { y: 8, x: '03/05/2014' }
]
```

in the case of deeper nested structures, small modifications need to be applied to accommodate them. eg.

```
const arrayX = [ ["02/01/2014", "14/10/2014", "03/05/2014"] ];
const arrayY = [2, 10, 8];

const data = arrayX[0].map((item, index) => ({ 
.....
```

Comment: Did you read the comment that explained that the problem is that the `arrayX` values are nested a level deeper. Other than that the code works.

Comment: I do not see an example of `nested a level deeper` -

Comment: You don't see the comment that begins with **You let me just notice that my 2 arrays (arrayX and array Y) I was receiving were given inside an array each**?